# random sample in python

Tags: python, performance, random, sample, xrange

I wanna speed this up:

```
import random
ndim = 50000
for i in xrange(ndim):
   random.sample([j for j in xrange(ndim) if j != i], 30000)
```

I'm thinking about using NumPy but don't know how.

Comment: What ways have you thought up and tried to speed it up?

Comment: What's the order of magnitude of ndim?

Comment: `[j for j in xrange(ndim) if j != i]` replaced by `range(0,i)+range(i+1,ndim)` with `ndim=50000` is about three times faster.

Comment: What do you do with these numbers afterwards?

Comment: I've run some numbers. Under the same conditions (ndim = 50000, sample size = 30000, extract 5000 samples, to keep it short), the NumPy version I proposed down there runs in my computer in ~10 seconds; the one proposed by Thomas Jung does it in ~110 seconds, and using the `range(i) + range(i+1, ndim)` that eumiro suggested would take around ~120 seconds, because it needs to build the whole range again every loop

Answer (score 1):

From [NumPy Docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.sample.html#numpy.random.sample) -

> numpy.random.sample(size=None)
>
> Return random floats in the half-open interval [0.0, 1.0).

```
>>> np.random.random_sample()
0.47108547995356098
>>> np.random.random_sample((5,))
array([ 0.30220482,  0.86820401,  0.1654503 ,  0.11659149,  0.54323428])
```

so if your `ndim = 50000`, then you could get a random sample from above & multiply it with `ndim` & round it off to an int. This could work...

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not take the `if j != i` part into account.

Comment: It looks to me as though the OP needs sampling without replacement, which is what the standard library `random.sample` does;  it's not clear how you'd achieve this with the approach outlined above.

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution using NumPy would be:

```
import numpy as np
from numpy.random import randint

ndim  = 50000
mndim = ndim -1
base = np.arange(1, ndim)
# addr = np.ones(mndim, dtype=int)
# addr[0] = 0
for i in xrange(5000):
     base[randint(0, mndim, 30000)]
     try:
        base[i] = i
     except IndexError:
        pass
```

Comment: Ahem... Forgot that you can index a NumPy array using an array... The edited one will work with older versions :)

Comment: Edited to combine the NumPy solution with the updating used by @ThomasJung. Reduces the runtime by ~30%

Comment: Hmm.  This isn't the same thing.  `random.sample` does sampling *without replacement*:  the result won't have repeated entries.  Your `base[randint(...)]` call doesn't prevent repeated entries.

Comment: Then it would be matter of testing `numpy.random.choice`, which allows for sampling without replacement, but that requires NumPy >= 1.7.0

Comment: There's `numpy.random.shuffle`, so you could use that and then slice the sample from that.  (I tried this, but actually got a result that was slower than `random.sample`.)

Comment: @MarkDickinson: yeah, I tried `np.random.shuffle` too and noticed it was rather slow, so I didn't event propose it.

Answer (score 1):

Using the list of allowed values `x` that is updated for the next round after it's used:

```
import random
s = 3000
ndim = 5000

x = range(1, ndim)
for i in xrange(ndim):
   random.sample(x, s)
   if(i < ndim - 1): x[i] = i #update
```